# CSS: Why is 'top: 0px' not positioning an absolutely positioned 'p' element within a relatively positioned div correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a div 'frame' with a position of relative, containing an image and descriptive text 'imgname'. I want the descriptive text to be at the top of the image, but when I set the top value to 0, the text is displayed slightly below the top of the 'frame' div. Here's the fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RwQL8/6/
I've corrected the problem [here in another version of the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwQL8/4/), by using a negative value for the 'top' line in the 'imgname' class, but why is this necessary? I tried putting '!important' after the  'top' value in my first fiddle, and it still displays incorrectly. Likewise for manually setting the line-height in case that was the source of the problem. Does anyone know why setting 'top' equal to 0 in my first fiddle was insufficient to display the text at the top, and a negative value is required? Here's my CSS code from the first fiddle:

```
.art {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 90%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center; }

.frameswrapper {
  font-size: 0; }

.frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tan;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden; }

.fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

.imgname {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16pt;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0px !important; }
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: See ngtCleaner's answer for the positioning discrepency (it was due to the browser defined margin for 'p' elements). If you're a new learner, you may be interested in Will's comment regarding CSS reset files, which might've prevented my problem.

EDIT: Seeing as this answer has gotten pretty popular, I wanted to summarize the above to help out people new to web design/development.

The problem I was experiencing was due to the fact that web browsers have default CSS styles for HTML elements (and different browsers have slightly different default styles). You might think that leaving an element, such as a P tag, sans declared styles would mean it has no 'active' styles, but you would be wrong, due to the aforementioned.

I would suggest using [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) - this is a stylesheet that standardizes browser default styles, which helps when creating your layout, as it gives you a better cross-browser foundation to work off. You could also use [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), which removes the default padding, margin and more of most elements (using this would've resolved the problem that originally prompted me to ask this question).

Comment: Before reading your post: Have you done this? `body, html {margin:0; padding:0;}`  If you have, I apologize and I'll read on.

Comment: Yep, I've defined that (and width: 100%) in a separate stylesheet. I also threw that into the jsfiddle to no effect.

Comment: This question is precisely why CSS Resets got so popular. By default, browsers add 1em of top and bottom margin. If you don't already, make sure you're web inspector of choice is also showing user agent CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Will. Just googled CSS resets and thats super cool - definitely going to incorporate this going forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your using a `<p>` element for your `.imgname` the webkit is giving a default margin of `1em`.  You have to specify your `.imgname` to have zero top and bottom margin.  I've changed your CSS from

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

to

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This will give your `<p>` element a zero top and bottom margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/RwQL8/7/

You could alternatively give your `<p>` element a margin of 0 right off the bat.

```
p { margin:0; }
```

and this will make sure all of your `<p>` will have zero margin, then your class style will overwrite that.

A note to your future coding: You should always specify all margins on something.  It's as easy as clockwork.

When writing a single margin line (i.e. `margin: 10px 20px 15px 5px;` You can read this as the first number being `top` and going clockwise from there.  `20px` is right, `15px` is bottom, `5px` is left.  It can also be written like so:

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: 5px;
```

If you use only two numbers, the first number corresponds with the top and bottom, while the second number corresponds with left and right.  i.e. `margin:10px 20px;` is the same as

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
```

You can also do the same with three numbers; `margin:10px 20px 5px` which means top:10px, bottom 5px and both left and right are 20px;

Comment: Thanks man, setting the p margin manually did the trick, and thanks for the margin tip.

Comment: Anytime! glad I could help