# Image Child can't be set to top of its parent

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is my issue:

[image]

My 'Test' image is a little too mouch below and I can't find how to reduve the top space to 0.
Basically, I'm using flex box to create 3 row: Title, Image and Description.

I set my image to w:426px and height:240px (to resize from a 1920x1080 image)

Any idea?
Here is my full code (noob in html/css sorry)

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='{{link}}';">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      <p id="title">{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <div id="image-container">
        <img id="image-source" src="{{image.url}}" alt="{{image.alt}}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p id="description">{{description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</button>

<style>
  button{
    background-image: {{background-image.url}};
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 600px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .flex-container > div{
    width: 426px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff00;
  }

  #title{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 426px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #image-container{
    width: 426px;
    height: 240px;
  }
  
  #image-source{
    width: 426px;
    height: 240px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
  }
  
  #description{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 426px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Thanks a lot ! I'll continue to search on my side :)

Comment: Neither div nor p are allowed as children of a button to begin with.

Comment: what's the parent of the button element?

Comment: I'm doing a custom gutemberg block using Lazy Block on Wordpress. I want to make a clickable section so the trio title-image-description is acting like a button.

Comment: Ha maybe the parent of my button, automatically set using a theme in Wordpress, is changing the behaviour of my image since it's from a theme?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found my issue thanks to this post : [CSS: Why is 'top: 0px' not positioning an absolutely positioned 'p' element within a relatively positioned div correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492048/css-why-is-top-0px-not-positioning-an-absolutely-positioned-p-element-with)

I had to add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to my image-source css